# ExtJs: Attaching form fields to in-memory objects

Tags: extjs

I'm not understanding some key bit of ExtJs idiom so this question is about guiding me towards that. I think I'm trying to use ExtJs in the wrong way.

I'm writing an application which allows the user to add a dynamic number of child records. Let's pretend I'm describing a room and the user can click the Add Door button and get a door FormPanel added to a list of FormPanels where they can specify the details of the door.

I'm holding the details of a door as an object in memory and I want to be able to connect the results of selecting a value in a combobox, textfield, etc with a field on the correct object. My plan is to then be able to send the object to the server using JSON/XHR/REST and persist it. I've got other processing that's going onto the door object (e.g. spatial) hence wanting to have my own.

So far, nothing I've tried has worked. I can hook the select event but either my scope is the field control (in which case I can't access the door object) or the scope is the door object and I can't access the value of the field control.

I'm getting a little confused because ExtJs talks about linking to hidden fields. However, it appears to want one and only one field with a given id for a given control. This means that I can't have more than one door unless the scope of that id is limited to the FormPanel.

Lastly, ideally I'd have a common store that was updated with new entries to the colour combobox so it could be shared by multiple doors. If anyone knows examples of this working I'd be grateful.

```
var doorDataEditor = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    labelWidth: 75,
    width: 350,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'colour',
            name: 'colour',
            xtype: 'combo',
            store: colourStore,
            displayField: 'name',
            typeAhead: true,
            mode: 'local',
            triggerAction: 'all',
            emptyText: 'Select the colour for this door...',
            selectOnFocus:true,
            value: door.colour,
            listeners:{
                scope: door,
                 'select': function(ev, target) {

                    alert(target.findField('name')); this.colour = target.value;
                } 
            }
        }]});
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the generic DOM event handler format (ev, target), but this is not a generic DOM event.  For components, you should look in the [API docs](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.ComboBox) for the appropriate component-specific event signature.  In this case, for ComboBox is `( Ext.form.ComboBox combo, Ext.data.Record record, Number index )`  You should be able to grab the value from `record.data.colour` (assuming that's how you have your records mapped).

Comment: Great! That was the insight I was missing. I hadn't connected the event list with documenting custom parameters.